# How does this error happened? 'IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable'

Tags: python, numpy

I am using Python 3.7 and Numpy 1.18.5.

I tried to run the following code:

```
import numpy as np

def rot(direc,ang):
    
    c=np.cos(ang)
    s=np.sin(ang)
    if direc=='x':
        R = np.block([[1, 0, 0],[0, c, -s],[0, s, c]])
    elif direc=='y':
        R = np.block([[c, 0, s],[0, 1, 0],[-s, 0, c]])
    elif direc=='z':
        R = np.block([[c, -s, 0],[s, c, 0],[0, 0, 1]])
    else:
        'Direction not recognized.'    
    
    return R

def Hjac(fun,x,reg):
    class HJAC():
        def __init__(self):
            self.z = np.spacing(shape=(6,1))
            self.A = np.spacing(shape=(6,10))

    z = np.vectorize(fun)
    n = np.size(x)
    m = np.size(z)
    A = np.empty(shape=(m,n))
    h = n*np.spacing(1)
    ns = range(0,n)
    for k in ns:
        x1 = x;
        x1[k] = x1[k]+h*1j
        A[:,k] = np.imag(z(x1,reg))/h

    HJacobi = HJAC()
    HJacobi.z = z
    HJacobi.A = A

    return HJacobi

def fun(x,reg):
    
    R = rot('x',reg[1])
    f = np.dot(R,x*reg)
    return f

x = np.random.rand(3,1)
reg = np.random.rand(3,1)

H = Hjac(fun,x,reg)
```

I am trying to obtain a jacobian of a function 'fun' with respect to a vector 'x'.

But I got the following error message:

```
runfile('C:/Users/2JY/Documents/Python/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/2JY/Documents/Python')
C:/Users/2JY/Documents/Python/temp.py:32: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  x1[k] = x1[k]+h*1j
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-8907a67fa932>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/2JY/Documents/Python/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/2JY/Documents/Python')

  File "C:\Users\2JY\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\2JY\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/2JY/Documents/Python/temp.py", line 50, in <module>
    H = Hjac(fun,x,reg)

  File "C:/Users/2JY/Documents/Python/temp.py", line 33, in Hjac
    A[:,k] = np.imag(z(x1,reg))/h

  File "C:\Users\2JY\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2091, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)

  File "C:\Users\2JY\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2161, in _vectorize_call
    ufunc, otypes = self._get_ufunc_and_otypes(func=func, args=args)

  File "C:\Users\2JY\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2121, in _get_ufunc_and_otypes
    outputs = func(*inputs)

  File "C:/Users/2JY/Documents/Python/temp.py", line 43, in fun
    R = rot('x',reg[1])

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

I changed `def fun(x,reg)` as:

```
def fun(x,reg):
    
    ang1 = reg[1]
    R = rot('x',ang1)
    f = np.dot(R,x*reg)
    return f
```

and I got the following error message:

```
  File "C:/Users/2JY/Documents/Python/temp.py", line 43, in fun
    ang1 = reg[1]

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

I can't understand why this kind of error happened.

I would really appreciate any answer to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: You are trying to index a non-iterable value. If you do not give us a minimally reproducible example it will be difficult to help. I suggest that this is a good opportunity to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: What's the `reg.shape`?  Is suspect `()`, 0d.  If so the only valid index is `reg[()]`.

Comment: @hpaulj The output of ```reg.shape``` is (3,1).

Comment: It may be (3,1) in you outer code, but not once it is passed through `vectorize`.  Look at the traceback.  I don't know why you are using `vectorize`, but you need to realize that it passes scalar values to your function (not arrays).  So `reg[1]` is producing this error.

Comment: @hpaulj Well, I'm trying to convert a Matlab code into Python code. I'm using ```vectorize``` because I'm new to Python and It would be different to call a custom function. After removing ```vectorize``` as ```z = fun(x,reg)```, the error disappeared. Thank you!